# Find if process is running in Windows psutil

Tags: python, windows, psutil

```
process_name = "CCC.exe"
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name == process_name:
        print ("have")
    else: 
        print ("Dont have")
```

I know for the fact that CCC.exe is running. I tried this code with both 2.7 and 3.4 python
I have imported psutil as well. However the process is there but it is printing "Dont have".

Comment: you have to remove else part? for other exes, you are simply printing "Dont have".

Comment: use `print(proc.name)` to see exactly what processes are running.

Comment: guys i have answered ny own question ..seems psutil is buggy WMI module works though

Comment: No, your code has a bug. It should be "if proc.name() == process_name(): ..." (missing parenthesis after 'name').
WMI module will be like 100x slower than psutil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified version that worked for me on Windows 7 with python v2.7

You were doing it in a wrong way here `if proc.name == process_name:` in your code. Try to `print proc.name` and you'll notice why your code didn't work as you were expecting.

Code:

```
import psutil
process_name = "System" 
for proc in psutil.process_iter(): 
    process = psutil.Process(proc.pid)# Get the process info using PID
    pname = process.name()# Here is the process name
    #print pname
    if pname == process_name: 
        print ("have") 
    else: print ("Dont have")
```

[Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=display&name=psutil#downloads) are some examples about how to use psutil. I just read them and figured out this solution, may be there is a better solution. I hope it was helpful.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with `if proc.name == process_name`

Comment: `if proc.name == process_name` didn't work for me. `print proc.name ` gives something like `<bound method Process.name of <psutil.Process(pid=4, name='System') at 27187376>>` and later on the if condition fails.

Comment: Unless windows is different to unix with psutil then it should work. If not using something like process.name() with the OP's original code is all that is needed. you don't need the pid to get the name

Comment: guys i have answered ny own question ..seems psutil is buggy WMI module works though

Comment: @DeepakTivari Well thats good! I just tried to demonstrate you why it was not working in your case and how to do this in psutil. :)

Answer (score 4):

`name` is a method of `proc`:

```
process_name = "CCC.exe"
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == process_name:
        print ("have")
    else: 
        print ("Dont have")
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using WMI instead of psutil. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/

install it on windows.

`import wmi
     c = wmi.WMI ()
     for process in c.Win32_Process ():
         if "a" in process.Name:
             print (process.ProcessId, process.Name)`